# Is there an option to automatically create environment variables when connecting to data source

Tags: power-automate, flow, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

In  Power Apps there is an option to automatically create environment variables when connecting to data source.

So in Power automate is there similar option? if not, then how we can manually create the environment variables representing sites and lists and then use them inside out power automate flows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new environment variable from solution. Follow below steps:

1. Sign in to Power Apps portal (make.powerapps.com), and then on the left pane select **Solutions**.
2. Open the solution where you want to create environment variable.
3. On the command bar, select **New > More**, and then select **Environment variable**.
4. Enter all details and click Save:

   [image]

**Microsoft documentation**: [Environment variables overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/environmentvariables)

In Power automate flow, you can add environment variables from **Dynamic content** section like:

[image]

Comment: but in my case the variable need to be site and a list and not text .. am i correct?

Comment: Yes, you can choose it in data type section.